# Carrierwave: store different name inside uploader column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

Is there a way to customize the string/filename that is stored in the column where the carrierwave uploader is mounted?

Example:

```rb
class MyModelUploader < CarrierwaveUploader::Base
  def method_that_customizes_string_to_be_stored
    if model.custom_filename.present?
      model.custom_filename
    else
      file.original_filename
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is and it is already there for you if you have installed carrierwave.
If you got `MyModelUploader` for example, you will have:

```rb
# uploads/my_model_uploader.rb

# Override the filename of the uploaded files:
# Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
# def filename
#   "something.jpg" if original_filename
# end
```